# Retrieving PHP Prepared Statement field data

Tags: php, mysqli

I am using the Mysqli extension and a PHP Prepared Statement `SELECT;` I don't know how many fields I have in the `SELECT` until I after I do the

```
$stmt->execute();
$fieldcnt = $stmt->field_count;
```

Because this, I am having problems doing a

```
$stmt->bind_result(list of parms);
```

Namely, since I don't know how many fields have been returned, I don't know how to contruct  the "list of parms."

So, I need some advice on how I access the fields returned;

Answer (score 1):

Don't use bind_result, and use [`fetch_assoc()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php).

This will return an associated array for each row:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fech_assoc()) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage `call_user_func_array()` to accomplish this task -- if you absolutely must use `bind_result()`.

```
// create an array the size of the number of parameters
$params = array_fill(0, $fieldcnt, null);

// call bind_result, resulting in every column of the result to be
// bound to a value in $params
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $params);

// take a look at all the params
print_r($params);
```